# Disk errors Event ID 51 on LSI MegaRAID 9240-8i in RAID 1

Tags: hard-drive, raid1, megaraid

I am working on a case of recurrent disk errors.

Server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
There are two main disks on a mirrored RAID.

There is also an additional drive that is used for backup and normally left unmounted to Windows. I'm not sure which disk is generating the errors.

Initially the errors were happening every day, sometime during the backup.

I downloaded the LSI MegaRAID Storage Manager and ran a consistency check on the logical drive, the results were OK. The errors stopped during the week, but happened again Sunday and Monday.
I ran a defrag on the logical drive from Windows.
I ran a checkdisk on the unmounted backup drive, no issues detected.

The errors again stopped over the week, then returned on Sunday and Monday.

Error description:
disk 51
An error was detected on peripheral \Device\Harddisk2\DR12 during a paging operation.

Does anybody have a suggestion what to do to fix the issue for good?
What is the function of locating the physical drives? Could that fix my issue?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the backup a USB disk? Sometime, I saw long-standing USB disks (eg: ones that are attached to a machine with long uptime and are not removed often) give all kind of errors, behaving erratically.

If it your case *and the message refers to the USB disk*, the message itself is effectively harmless. [Here you can find some more information.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244780)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes the backup HDD is a USB. I haven't been able to confirm for sure if the disk errors are generated by the logical RAID or the backup disk.